# A doubt in complex analysis with respect to entire functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Show that
If $(\Re f)^2 ≤ (\Im f)^2$, then $f$ is constant.

I have tried solving this question and I am not very sure if my reasoning is valid.
The approach goes like this:
Let $f = u+iv$.

Since $f$ is an entire function, so is $f^2$.
Now $f^2 = u^2-v^2 + i2uv$

Since the real part of $f^2$ is bounded as per the condition in the question $u^2-v^2<0$ and the function is entire, we can conclude that $f^2$ is a constant function with the help of Liouvilles's theorem.

Now either $f$ could be a constant throughout or it could take two values  say a constant C and -C.
But since $f$  is entire, it must be continuous.
It seems that if the value of $f$ oscillates between two numbers it can not be continuous and hence $f$ should take a single value which proves that it is constant.
Is this logic correct?

Is it possible for a function to be entire and take only two values?

Comment: There is no continuous function taking exactly two values by connectedness of the complex plane.

Comment: @Kashish, you should post a new question if you have one, instead of editing an existing one, especially if people have already answered the original version of the existing one.

Comment: @Bungo Yes , I would take care of it next time. Although this question also asks the same question as the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by finite complex plane, you mean the whole plane as the definition of entire requires. If you do, then an entire function that takes only two values would be bounded by the max of the norm of the two values, hence a constant function by Liouville's Theorem.